# Tensorflow CNN model perform good in train set, but poor in validation set

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, neural-network

I have build a cnn model (regression) using tensorflow. But it performs good in train set but poor in validation/test set.  Below is the curve of loss, the red line is loss of train set, and the blue line is for validation set:

[image]

Is this overfitting? I try to use regularzation and dropout in it, the the result is not changed.

This is my model and loss function:

```
def weight_variable(shape, reg = False):
    initial = tf.truncated_normal(shape, stddev=0.1)
    #initial = tf.random_uniform(shape)
    w = tf.Variable(initial)
    if reg:
        tf.add_to_collection('reg', w)
    return w

def bias_variable(shape):
    initial = tf.constant(0.1, shape=shape)
    return tf.Variable(initial)

def conv2d(x, W, stride):
    return tf.nn.conv2d(x, W, strides=[1, stride, stride, 1], padding='VALID')

def cnn_steer():

    with tf.name_scope('input'):
        x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 66, 200, 3])
        y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None])

    with tf.name_scope('keep_prob'):
        keep_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)

    x_image = x

    with tf.name_scope('conv1'):
        # first convolutional layer
        W_conv1 = weight_variable([5, 5, 3, 24])
        b_conv1 = bias_variable([24])

        h_conv1 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(x_image, W_conv1, 2) + b_conv1)


    with tf.name_scope('conv2'):
        # second convolutional layer
        W_conv2 = weight_variable([5, 5, 24, 36])
        b_conv2 = bias_variable([36])

        h_conv2 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(h_conv1, W_conv2, 2) + b_conv2)


    with tf.name_scope('conv3'):
        # third convolutional layer
        W_conv3 = weight_variable([5, 5, 36, 48])
        b_conv3 = bias_variable([48])

        h_conv3 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(h_conv2, W_conv3, 2) + b_conv3)


    with tf.name_scope('conv4'):
        # fourth convolutional layer
        W_conv4 = weight_variable([3, 3, 48, 64])
        b_conv4 = bias_variable([64])

        h_conv4 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(h_conv3, W_conv4, 1) + b_conv4)


    with tf.name_scope('conv5'):
        # fifth convolutional layer
        W_conv5 = weight_variable([3, 3, 64, 64])
        b_conv5 = bias_variable([64])

        h_conv5 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(h_conv4, W_conv5, 1) + b_conv5)

    with tf.name_scope('fc1'):
        # fully connected layer 1
        W_fc1 = weight_variable([1152, 1164], True)
        b_fc1 = bias_variable([1164])

        h_conv5_flat = tf.reshape(h_conv5, [-1, 1152])
        h_fc1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(h_conv5_flat, W_fc1) + b_fc1)

        h_fc1_drop = tf.nn.dropout(h_fc1, keep_prob)

    with tf.name_scope('fc2'):
        # fully connected layer 2
        W_fc2 = weight_variable([1164, 100], True)
        b_fc2 = bias_variable([100])

        h_fc2 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(h_fc1_drop, W_fc2) + b_fc2)

        h_fc2_drop = tf.nn.dropout(h_fc2, keep_prob)

    with tf.name_scope('fc3'):
        # fully connected layer 3
        W_fc3 = weight_variable([100, 50], True)
        b_fc3 = bias_variable([50])

        h_fc3 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(h_fc2_drop, W_fc3) + b_fc3)

        h_fc3_drop = tf.nn.dropout(h_fc3, keep_prob)

    with tf.name_scope('fc4'):
        # fully connected layer 4
        W_fc4 = weight_variable([50, 10], True)
        b_fc4 = bias_variable([10])

        h_fc4 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(h_fc3_drop, W_fc4) + b_fc4)

        h_fc4_drop = tf.nn.dropout(h_fc4, keep_prob)

    with tf.name_scope('output'):
        # output
        W_fc5 = weight_variable([10, 1])
        b_fc5 = bias_variable([1])


        # y = tf.multiply(tf.atan(tf.matmul(h_fc4_drop, W_fc5) + b_fc5), 2)
        y = tf.matmul(h_fc4_drop, W_fc5) + b_fc5

    return x, y_, y, keep_prob
```

And the loss function is:

```
regularizer = tf.contrib.layers.l2_regularizer(scale = 0.02)
reg_var = tf.get_collection('reg')
reg_term = tf.contrib.layers.apply_regularization(regularizer, reg_var)
loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(y_actual - tf.transpose(y_predict)))
r_loss = loss + reg_term
```

The keep_prob I used is 0.6

Can someone tell me what's wrong with my model?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is your data? And do you know that the training and validation sets are similar enough to one another that a classifier trained on one *should* generalize to the other?

Comment: Data is RGB iamges which show the detail of the road. It get by a camera at the top of the vehicle. In fact, i want to train a simple self-driving model. I collect about 20,000 iamges, and shuffle them. So i think training and validation sets should be similar.

Comment: Btw, it performs good when i use this model to drive a car in game (I use GTA V to test the model)

Comment: What's your split between training and validation data? How many samples in each set?

Comment: I shuffle the data set and save them in a new file, then put 80% as training set (about 16,000), 20% as validation set (about 4,000) in order from the shuffled set.

Comment: Your training data starts off doing much worse than your test data (which is a huge red flag that something isn't set up properly), and ends up doing much better.  Plus the results for your test data are essentially unchanged throughout.  I have to agree with Engineero, except to me it looks like you somehow have two entirely separate graphs and the one you're running the test data on is never being trained.  If you post all of your code we might be able to find something.